# How to access externally to consul UI

Tags: consul

How can I access to consul UI externally?

I want to access consul UI writing

`<ANY_MASTER_OR_SLAVE_NODE_IP>:8500`

I have try doing a ssh tunnel to acces:
ssh -N -f -L 8500:localhost:8500 root@172.16.8.194

Then if I access http://localhost:8500
It works, but it is not what I want. I need to access externally, without ssh tunnel.

My config.json file is the next:

```
{
"bind_addr":"172.16.8.216",
"server": false,
"datacenter": "nyc2",
"data_dir": "/var/consul",
"ui_dir": "/home/ikerlan/dist",
"log_level": "INFO",
"enable_syslog": true,
"start_join": ["172.16.8.211","172.16.8.212","172.16.8.213"]
}
```

Any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Add

```
{
  "client_addr": "0.0.0.0"
}
```

to your configuration or add the option `-client 0.0.0.0` to the command line of consul to make your Web UI accessible from the outside ([see the docs for more information](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/options.html)).

Please note that this will also make your Consul REST API accessible from the outside. Depending on your environment you might want to activate Consul's ACLs to restrict access.

Comment: If I add "client_addr":"0.0.0.0" to my configuration the client go out of the cluster, and when I run consul members on the client: "Error connecting to Consul agent: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8400: connection refused". If I run -client 0.0.0.0 on my command line: "-client: command not found" What could be the problem? @ahus1

Comment: @Asier I have updated the description. If your client goes out of the cluster, please have a look at consul log file. Maybe there is a syntax error in your configuration. the `-client` option needs to be part of the command line of your consul executable. Please have a look at the referenced consul documentation. I also updated the answer to make it more explicit.

Comment: I take the line "client_addr":"0.0.0.0" to my config.json file, and if I have this configuration the node cant connect with the others, I have a error when I execute consul members. Sure that the unique configuration I have to do is edit the config.json and insert this line? Thanks @ahus1

Comment: For the clients to connect to each consul will bind an interface with a private IP address. You can manually select the IP address with the `bind` parameter. By default this IP address is advertised to the other clients, but you can override this with the `advertise` configuration parameter. Please see here https://github.com/ahus1/saltconsul-examples for a full setup of consul with Salt and either Vagrant or Digital Ocean. See cheatsheet.adoc for a fast track.

Comment: I have add the IP with the bind parameter, as you can see in the description there was my config.json. My problem is that if add the next line client_addr":"0.0.0.0" to my config.json it fails.  @ahus1

Comment: THANK YOU!  That was not obvious from the documentation!

Answer (score 5):

You can use socat in this case.

> socat -d -d TCP-L:8500,bind=172.16.93.128,fork TCP:localhost:8500 &

where 172.16.93.12 is my IP.

Answer (score 4):

Finally I find the solution.
Add to the config file with the bind addr that is the IP of the machine, and the client_addr that is the hosts he listen to. So I use 0.0.0.0 to listen to all the IPs.

```
"bind_addr":"<machine-ip>",
"client_addr":"0.0.0.0",
```

Answer (score 4):

I run it as a docker image, i gave

```
docker pull consul

docker run -p 8500:8500 consul
```

and i am able to access the consul ui at `http://<hostname>:8500/ui`

Answer (score 2):

I don't have hands-on experience with Consul yet, but here are a few tips:

- Run `sudo netstat -peanut | grep :8500` and check if Consul is bound to 0.0.0.0 or an explicit ip. Should check docs if this is configurable.
- On each node install [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/), [Nginx](https://www.nginx.com/) or any other software which can act as a HTTP proxy

Comment: If I run "sudo netstat -peanut | grep :8500" I can see: tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8500          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN, Is not anyway to do without installing Nginx or other packages? Thanks @NikoNyrh

Comment: ahus1 seems to know the docs better, you should get it configured that it isn't bound on `127.0.0.1` because then it won't accept external connections.

Answer (score 0):

No way to get User Interface if ther no user interface )
Classic UI its some stack of Desktop Environment(x-term....), so before get, you need install it on node

Comment: I have install the User Inteface, I can acces it with a ssh tunnel, but I want to access without ssh tunnel, writting http://172.16.8.194:8500